# Count number of rows which contain words

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a dataset with many rows that contain fruit descriptions e.g:

```
An apple hangs on an apple tree
Bananas are yellow and tasty 
The apple is tasty
```

I need to find unique words in this description (
I've already done it) and then I have to count in how many rows are those unique words appear.
Example:

```
Apple 2 (rows)
Bananas 1 (rows)
tree 1 (rows)
tasty 2 (rows)
```

I've done something like that:

```
rows <- data_frame %>%
  filter(str_detect(variable, "apple"))
count_rows <- as.data.frame(nrow(rows))
```

But the problem is that I have too many unique words so I don't want to do it manually. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a list of words for which you want the count?

Comment: Yes, I have a list.

Comment: It works! Thank you all for your help :D

Answer (score 2):

One `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `tibble` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 mutate(sentences = strsplit(sentences, " ", fixed = TRUE)) %>%
 unnest(sentences) %>%
 mutate(sentences = tolower(sentences)) %>%
 filter(sentences %in% list_of_words) %>%
 group_by(sentences) %>%
 summarise_all(n_distinct)

  sentences rowid
  <chr>     <int>
1 apple         2
2 bananas       1
3 tasty         2
4 tree          1
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(sentences = c("An apple hangs on an apple tree",
                               "Bananas are yellow and tasty",
                               "The apple is tasty"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   

list_of_words <- tolower(c("Apple", "Bananas", "tree", "tasty"))
```

Comment: unnest function is unknown.

Comment: use library(tidyr). My problem is Error in rowid_to_column(.) : could not find function "rowid_to_column" How can I resolve?

Comment: @Inuraghe the function is in the library tibble.

Answer (score 1):

In base R this can be done like the following.

```
r <- apply(sapply(words, function(s) grepl(s, df[[1]], ignore.case = TRUE)), 2, sum)
as.data.frame(r)
#        r
#Apple   2
#Bananas 1
#tree    1
#tasty   2
```

**Data.**

```
x <-
"'An apple hangs on an apple tree'
'Bananas are yellow and tasty' 
'The apple is tasty'"

x <- scan(textConnection(x), what = character())
df <- data.frame(x)

words <- c("Apple", "Bananas", "tree", "tasty")
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution would be to use `grepl` with `sapply` or `lapply`:

```
sapply(list_of_words, function(x) sum(grepl(x, tolower(df$sentences), fixed = T)))
apple bananas    tree   tasty 
    2       1       1       2
```